# Problema con los datos de un tester

Tags: java, test

He creado este programa para pasar de grados Celsius a Farenheit y al revés:

```
    public class Temperatura {

        
   private double  tempF, tempC;
   
   public void setFarenheit(double f) {
       tempF = f;
   
    }
   public void setCelsius(double c) {
       tempC = c;
       
   }
   public double celsiusToFarenheit() {
       return (1.8*tempC)+32;
   }
   public double farenheitToCelsius() {
       return (tempF-32)/1.8;
   }


}
```

Para comprobar que el programa funcionaba he creado este tester:

```
public class TemperaturaPrueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Temperatura convTemp;
        convTemp = new Temperatura();
        convTemp.setCelsius(100);
        convTemp.setFarenheit(212);
        System.out.println(c + " grados Celsius son " + 
                    convTemp.celsiusToFarenheit() + " grados Farenheit");
        System.out.println(f + "grados Farenheit son " +
                    convTemp.farenheitToCelsius() + "grados Celsius");
        
    }

}
```

Sin embargo, me da error en los datos c y f y no consigo que el tester funcione. ¿Alguna posible solución? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Las imágenes no son bien recibidas en la comunidad a no ser que sea extrictamente necesarias, que no es tu caso. te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, copiar tu código y pegarlo cono texto. Así, si algún miembro de la comunidad desea contestarte y probar tu código sólo necesitará copiarlo y no tener que reescribirlo de cero. Un saludo

Comment: Ok muchas gracias. Ya he editado la pregunta.

Comment: c y f no existen en main. Te falta crear los getters para getCelsius y getF.. slds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las variables c y f las tienes declaradas en la clase temperatura, pero no son visibles desde el método main

Una forma de recibir el varlor, sería con un retorno creando métodos get y al llamarlo recoger ese valor de retorno

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Temperatura convTemp;
    convTemp = new Temperatura();
    //debes de almacenar en una variable el valor de retorno
    double c = convTemp.setCelsius(100);
    //debes de almacenar en una variable el valor de retorno
    double f = convTemp.setFarenheit(212);
    System.out.println(c + " grados Celsius son " + 
                convTemp.celsiusToFarenheit() + " grados Farenheit");
    System.out.println(f + "grados Farenheit son " +
                convTemp.farenheitToCelsius() + "grados Celsius");
    
}
```

O de lo contrario hacerlo de forma manual con variables

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Temperatura convTemp;
    convTemp = new Temperatura();
    int c = 100;
    convTemp.setCelsius(c);
    int f = 212;
    convTemp.setFarenheit(f);
    System.out.println(c + " grados Celsius son " + 
            convTemp.celsiusToFarenheit() + " grados Farenheit");
    System.out.println(f + "grados Farenheit son " +
            convTemp.farenheitToCelsius() + "grados Celsius");    
}
```

Y otra forma sería con un menú, variables y pidiendo la temperatura a convertir por teclado

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Temperatura convTemp;
    convTemp = new Temperatura();
    int c = 0, f = 0;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Que desea haces:");
    System.out.println("1 - Convertir grados Centígrados a Farenheit");
    System.out.println("2 - Convertir grados Centígrados a Farenheit");
    System.out.println("3 - Cerrar");
    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println("Ponga una opción");
    int opcion = teclado.nextInt();
    
    if (opcion == 1){
        System.out.println("Introduzca los grados Farenheit:");
        f = teclado.nextInt();
        convTemp.setCelsius(f);
        System.out.println(f + " grados Celsius son " + 
                convTemp.celsiusToFarenheit() + " grados Farenheit");
    }
    else if (opcion == 2){
        System.out.println("Introduzca los grados Centígrados:");
        c = teclado.nextInt();
        convTemp.setFarenheit(c);
        System.out.println(c + " grados Farenheit son " +
                convTemp.farenheitToCelsius() + " grados Celsius");
    }
    else if (opcion == 3){
        System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```